# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker deployment failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Has anyone encountered failed deployment when deploying docker app to aws eb?

Here's a piece of log

> time="2016-09-20T09:36:42.802106539Z" level=error msg="Handler for DELETE /v1.23/containers/c7bc72d9ccec returned error: You cannot remove a running container c7bc72d9ccec6557ddca8e90c7c77b350cb0c80be9a90921478adccd70a2b97a. Stop the container before attempting removal or use -f" 
>   time="2016-09-20T09:36:42.924322201Z" level=error msg="Handler for DELETE /v1.23/images/9daab71ad3c0 returned error: conflict: unable to delete 9daab71ad3c0 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container c7bc72d9ccec" 
>   time="2016-09-20T09:36:42.924865908Z" level=error msg="Handler for DELETE /v1.23/images/dbcc41959b55 returned error: conflict: unable to delete dbcc41959b55 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images"

For the first time of the environment deployment, it works well. However, every time I deploy a new version of the app, it fails.

Running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.6 | Docker 1.11.2

My Dockerfile is rather simple:

```
# Get Node Latest
FROM node:6.5.0

# Create working directory
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

# Install depencencies
RUN npm install

# Expost 3000 port
EXPOSE 3000

# Start app
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `npm install` might take too long to run, cuz once I put node_modules into the zip and remove `npm install` from Dockerfile, it takes 3-5 minutes for deploying now.

Comment: Is it really the couse? Or you had some problem with npm install during the build...

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but last time I checked it's successfully been done by yarn install. Maybe it's the timeout?

Comment: Just check your logs: eb ssh, less /var/log/eb-activity, less /var/log/docker, less /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/***.log, log in to container: sudo docker ps, sudo docker exec -it <NAME> bash